# Смысл регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Хочу получить список классов некоторого типа элементов. Нашел ответ на [Получение списка классов](https://coderoad.ru/1227286/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-jQuery). Возник вопрос:

1. "Что означает регулярное выражение /\s+/ ?"
2. "Почему нельзя использовать " " при получении списка классов?"

Answer (score 1):

`\s` - это пробельный символ. Например пробел или таб или перенос строки.

В регулярных выражениях его часто используют просто на всякий случай, если не нужно только именно пробелы учитывать.

В данном случае если в коде вместо пробела окажется таб или перенос строки, при которых код остаётся верным, вы "бесплатно" получаете работоспособный код.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, может поможет ответ на этот вопрос в английской версии:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209362/what-is-the-meaning-of-s-s-gm-in-javascript/49209464

Answer (score 0):

`/\s+/` означает любое количество пробельных символов подряд, включая собственно пробелы, табуляцию, переводы строк. Поскольку между именами классов может быть непредсказуемое количество пробелов, использовать это регулярное выражение безопаснее, чем делить по строке с одним пробельным символом.